# How do I attach Ormlite database file to email intent in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, email, android-intent, ormlite

I'm maintaining a legacy Android app that uses OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper to create a Sqlite database on the device. On the device, I found out this file lives at:

**/data/data/[package-name]/databases/mydatabase.db**

My app has an "E-mail Support" feature, and I have unfortunately been tasked with attaching this SQLite file to an e-mail Intent for troubleshooting user issues. I'm running into some permission problems. Here is the code I'm using:

```
public void email(String[] to, String subject ) {
    Intent email    = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.setType("*/*");
    email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject );

    File file = activity.get().getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("mydatabase.db");

    if( file.exists() )  
    {
         if( file.canRead() )
        {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            activity.get().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Email DB File"));
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code and choose "Gmail" as my mail client, I get a toast on the e-mail client saying "Permission denied for attachment".

Why does this happen? How can I grant permission to Gmail on this file? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this, but I'm still open to other solutions.

If I create a temporary copy of the file on SD card using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), the Gmail client has permission to read this file. Mail client seems to only have permission issues accessing internal storage.

```
 File file = activity.get().getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("mydatabase.db");

    if( file.exists() && file.canRead() )
    {
        try {

           //We need to make a local copy of the file to SDCard, so Gmail can use it
            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "database_copy.db");
            this.copy(file, destination);

            //Attach file and send
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(destination);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            activity.get().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Email DB File"));
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            return;
        }
    }

....

//File copy routine
 private void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```